# json not getting printed in the correct order

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I have a json file named places.json. the contents are

```
{
    "Europe": [
        {
            "name": "London",
            "country": "England"
        },
        {
            "name": "Paris",
            "country": "France"
        }
    ],
    "Asia": [
        {
            "name": "Delhi",
            "country": "India"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tokyo",
            "country": "Japan"
        }
    ],
    "Africa": [
        {
            "name": "CapeTown",
            "country": "SouthAfrica"
        },
        {
            "name": "Abuja",
            "country": "Nigeria"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is just a part of the file.The file quite big.

Now I am getting this file through angular js as

```
myApp.controller('cityController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('places.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    }).error(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

And then I am printing the data in my html page as

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,val) in items">
   <p> {{key}}</p>
   <div ng-repeat="place in val">
      <p>{{place.name}}</p>
      <p>{{place.country}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am getting the output but not in the correct order. (i.e) I am getting Asia printed first with its places and Europe and so on. Why is this happening. How can I get printed in the correct order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the order of keys in an object is not defined. most browsers implement them ordered alphabatically, but they may be returned in which order they ever want.
if you need them to be ordered you will have to put them into an array instead and put the name of each into a new property (e.g. "name")

Definition of an Object from [ECMAScript Third Edition (pdf)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf):

> 4.3.3 Object An object is a member of the type Object. **It is an unordered collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive
>   value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an
>   object is called a method.

Comment: Thankyou. I will change the json format and store the continent name also in a property

Comment: np, can you mark the answer as correct though?